# React 'String' prop passing down as an 'object'

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have 2 components like below in my application:

```
<Comp1>
...
    <Comp2 prop1='test1' prop2='test2'/>
    <Comp3 prop1='test1 />
</Comp1>
```

The Comp2 and Comp3 components look like below:

```
const Comp2 = (prop1, prop2) => {
...
...
}
Comp2.propTypes = {
prop1: PropTypes.string.isrequired,
prop2: PropTypes.string.isrequired,
}


const Comp3 = prop1 => (
...
...
)
Comp2.propTypes = {
prop1: PropTypes.string.isrequired,
}
```

As we can see from above, I am passing a string value 'test1' from Comp1 into 2 components - Comp2 and Comp3.

Comp2 receives a string value for 'prop1' as 'test1' - as expected.

However, Comp3 receives the same property 'prop1' as an object instead of a string. So in Comp3, prop1 is not equal to string 'test1', but it is equal to 'prop1: test1' in the shape of a Json object. I am not able to figure out why the same property is passing down as different types for both components when they are defined in a very similar manner.

Could someone please help me understand how this is going on? Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please remember that functional components take only one parameter and it is called `props`. So whatever the `prop` you want to access, you have to reference it as `props.prop`. In your components, you can take these values with `object destructuring` as shown below.

```
const Comp2 = ({prop1, prop2}) => {
...
...
}

const Comp3 = ({ prop1 }) => (
...
...
)
```

So your error is expected, because you are taking `props` which is an object.

Comment: That is correct, thank you much for pointing it out. It solved my problem.